# I want to delete all the files under a directory using shell script, passing file directory as an argument

Tags: linux, shell

Sample command:

**./delete.sh /path/to/location**

|-Path
|-to
|-location
|- file1
|- file2
|- file3
.
.
|- fileN

Need to delete all the files(file1,file2,file3.....fileN) inside location directory using script

Comment: `rm -rf /path/to/locaton`

Comment: this will delete the folder itself..but i want to delete the files inside that folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the find command for this:

```
find "$1" -maxdepth 1 -type f -delete
```

Pass the directory as a parameter in the scripts ($1) and then ensure you are only searching the directory at one level with -maxdepth 1 and searching for files only with -f. Delete what ever is found with -delete.